# How to prevent addClass and removeClass repetition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding active class to the buttons, and also i'm adding list/grid class to the cards-wrapper based on the button clicked. 
Below is the working code. is there a way to write less code to achieve the same output?

```js
$('.buttons button').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('button').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');

    if ($(this).hasClass('list')) {
        $('.cards-wrapper').removeClass('grid').addClass('list');
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass('grid')) {
        $('.cards-wrapper').removeClass('list').addClass('grid');
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="grid">Grid</button>
  <button class="list active">List</button>
</div>

<div class="cards-wrapper list">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is seeking optimisation/improvements and belongs to [CodeReviews](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [toggleClass method](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/). As the name suggests, this method toggles the given classes for all the elements in the selection.

You can reduce your if/else logic to just one if statement by checking whether the button that was clicked on is not active. Once you have established that the button is not active, you can then just toggle the classes for both of the buttons and for the content wrapper div.

```js
$('.buttons button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $('button').toggleClass('active');
        $('.cards-wrapper').toggleClass('grid list');
    }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
}
.list {
  color: red;
}
.grid {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <button>Grid</button>
  <button class="active">List</button>
</div>

<div class="cards-wrapper list">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
</div>
```

Using the `toggleClass` method in this way will break if you add more buttons, though, so take care with it.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much you can do there as you are having two action buttons, if you can make it into a single one, then you can use jQuery's `.toggleClass()` method here. Hence, you don't have to check for classes using `.hasClass()` every time.

```
$('.buttons button').click(function(e) {
  //some of your code here

  $('.cards-wrapper').toggleClass('grid list');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `toggleClass()` function of jquery

1. In your answer `addClass()` and `removeClass()` .its right.
2. But better use with `toggleClass()`.because toggle function to check the class name already present or not.if is it present to remove the class name ,is not add the class.
3. Its handle with one or more function .See the jquery documentation of 
   [**`toggleClass()`**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

   ```js
   $('.buttons button').click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $('button').toggleClass('active');
   if($(this).hasClass('list')){
           $('.cards-wrapper').toggleClass('grid  list');
       }
       else if($(this).hasClass('grid')) {
           $('.cards-wrapper').toggleClass('list grid');
       }
   });
   ```

   ```css
   .active{

   color:green !important;
   }
   .list{
   color:red;
   }
   .grid{
   color:blue;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div class="buttons">
     <button class="grid">Grid</button>
     <button class="list active">List</button>
   </div>

   <div class="cards-wrapper list">
     <div>Sample Content</div>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: If you are using `toggleClass`, Why do you need `if..else?`

Comment: @Rajesh because the classes will toggle regardless of the button OP is pressing.

Comment: @Mr.Alien I noticed that, but this stupid attempt was highlight prasad that such gaps in information will come and he should clarify them in answer. *Try with toggleClass() function of jquery* is not an explanation. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ternary` operator not `toggleClass()` because it will cost bug.

```js
$('.buttons button').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('button').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $(this).hasClass('list') ? $('.cards-wrapper').removeClass('grid').addClass('list') : '';
      $(this).hasClass('grid') ? $('.cards-wrapper').removeClass('list').addClass('grid') : '';
});
```

```css
.active{

color:green !important;
}
.list{
color:red;
}
.grid{
color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="grid">Grid</button>
  <button class="list active">List</button>
</div>

<div class="cards-wrapper list">
  <div>Sample Content</div>
</div>
```